# how to hide data/message of push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I have successfully implement the `fcm notification` using java server but I want to show only one string in notification instead of all message so how to hide data and send only some  data of message.
for e.g "refresh data common" I want to show only refresh data in notification message and hide common but common word requires on app side.

```
private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound)
{
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
           /* .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.space)*/
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

In this code I have pass only "refresh data" but it show all"{message=refresh data common}".

Comment: If you don't what to show "common" why are you sending it in 1st place..You can send "refresh data" right ?

Comment: i think you have not implemented Notification(app notification) properly. You can use remoteview for custom views. you can get lot of resources on google.

Comment: yes but i want common  word on app side .how can I get it?

Comment: add the necessary details and code to produce the issue

Comment: @nikitashelar There is an advanced option in FCM console.You can customise the message as you want..

Comment: @sunil  I'm not sending notification using fcm console .I have create own server for sending notification.is there any option using java server ?

Comment: @nikitashelar kk. I don't have much knowledage in  java server side..In client side you can split the text ,I guess title is your "refresh data common" split by space and append 1st and 2nd set.It's a workaround better will be doing in server side itself.

Comment: @sunil thanks this logic works for me at client side